# Printf on bytearray

Tags: c, printf

I have the following struct:

```
/** The description of an ordinary 8+3 DOS directory entry. */
struct  dirent
{
    byte    d_name[8];  //!< space padded name
    byte    d_ext[3];   //!< space padded extension

    byte    d_attr;     //!< the file attributes

    ......
};

printf("%s\n", de.d_name);
```

The problem I'm facing is with the printing of d_name I get the following output:
*'INSTALL BAT!'* which is not the 8 chars I was expecting at most.

My guess is the printf function continues to search in memory for a string terminator character even though it exceeded the d_name boundary.

Is there a way to only get the 'INSTALL' printed or do I need to loop through the entire byte array and print the chars individually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To print a char array that is space-padded (but not necessarily null-terminated) you can use a width specifier for printf:

```
printf("%.*s\n", sizeof de.d_name, de.d_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameterized your string as follows;

```
printf("%.8s", de.d_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

A char array with 8 elements cannot hold a string of length 8. You need 9 elements for that.

Or, to put it another way: a char array without a `'\0'` char anywhere in its elements is not a string. You cannot print it with `"%s"`.